# Detecting None-Scalar and None-tuple?

Tags: python

Just of curiosity I'm trying to detect None-Scalar and None-tuple with short-code to use in lambda ... i.e. using isinstance is cumbersome.

So possible values are :

```
None
(None, 0)
Value
(Value, 1)
```

so far `not (not x or not x[0])` , works for the cases 1,2,4, but not the 3rd

```
xx = lambda x: not( not x or not x[0] )
xx(None)  => False
xx((None,0)) => False
xx(5)

TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: It would be simpler to *always* use a `tuple`, representing `None` as `(None, None)` and `Value` as `(Value, None)`. Then, I believe,  `xx = lambda v: v[0] is not None` is the function you want.

Comment: thats what i did at the end ..

Answer (score 2):

You'll want some form of `is not None` to distinguish `None` from a `0` value.

There's really no way to distinguish a pair from a number by coercing to a boolean. The non-empty tuples will always be truthy, the None will always be falsy, but the number could be either true or false (when 0).

You can do it in one line without using `isinstance()` by using `type()` instead:

```
lambda x: {tuple: x}.get(type(x), [x])[0] is not None
# or
lambda x: (x[0] if type(x) is tuple else x) is not None
```

The advantage of `isinstance()` is that it works with subclasses.

---

Or with a standard library import:

```
from unittest.mock import ANY

lambda x: x not in [None, (None, ANY)]
```

This kind of thing is easy in languages that have *pattern matching*. (Which Python might be getting soon, see [PEP 622](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622/).) I'm (ab)using the `ANY` mock to achieve a similar effect.

Be careful with `ANY`. It works by overriding `.__eq__()` and `.__ne__()`, so it's not necessarily reflexive.

Comment: is PEP622  Unification ? like prolog or struct-matching in erlang ?

Comment: No, unification is even more general than pattern matching. Unification can bind a variable on either side of the relation. In contrast, pattern matching is one-way. There is a unification library for Python though: https://github.com/mrocklin/unification/ (There's also a kanren based on that.)

Comment: i know ;) i wrote my own ~prolog interpreter : http://www.igrok.site/bi/Bi_language.html

Comment: i like his function dispatch capability ... was looking for it in python ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using truthy-testing for that is dangerous because it misfires for

```
''     # empty string
0      # integer zero
[]     # empty list
False  # boolean False
set()  # empty other iterable
dict()
# etc.
```

because they all are Falsy - like `None`.

```
# Problem:
xx(0) # False
xx( ([],42) ) # False
```

See [pythong.org truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

Create a function and use it instead/inside your lambda:

```
data = [None,  (None, 0),  "g",  ("g", 1), 0, ([],42)]

def test(thing):
    """Returns 'False' for None and iterable inputs that have
    None as first value."""
    if thing is None: 
        return False
    try:
        a, *b = thing
        if a is None: 
            return False
    except: # purposefully not catching specific
        pass
    return True

for d in data:
    print(d, test(d))
```

Output:

```
None False
(None, 0) False
g True
('g', 1) True 
0 True
([], 42) True
```